# Go Differentiate Between Structs with same name in the same package

Tags: reflection, go, identifier

**Background:**

I am trying to cache some struct information for efficiency but am having trouble differentiating between struct with the same name, within the same package.

**Example Code:**

```
func Struct(s interface{}){
  val := reflect.ValueOf(s)
  typ := val.Type()

  // cache in map, but with what key? 
  typ.Name()               // not good enough
  typ.PkgPath + typ.Name() // not good enough
}

func Caller1() {
  type Test struct {
    Name string
  }

  t:= Test{
    Name:"Test Name",
  }

  Struct(t)
}

func Caller2() {
  type Test struct {
    Address string
    Other string
  }

  t:= Test{
    Address:"Test Address",
    Other:"OTHER",
  }

  Struct(t)
}
```

**Problem**

Can't find a proper unique key as:

- Name is the same "Test"
- PkgPath with be identical as both functions are in same package
- Pointers etc is out because need a consistent key otherwise caching would be pointless

Can anyone help in finding a way to uniquely identify these structs?

P.S. I do realize that changing of the struct name would solve the issue, but need to handle this scenario as I have a generic library that others will be calling and may have the structs defined like the above example.

Comment: Use `reflect.Type` as the map key.

Comment: Perfect Thanks! I had used that elsewhere in my code, guess I just needed a fresh pair of eyes; couldn't see the forest because of the trees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To uniquely identify types in a map, use [`reflect.Type`](https://godoc.org/reflect#Type) as the map key:

```
var cache map[reflect.Type]cachedType
```

This is recommended by the [reflect documentation](https://godoc.org/reflect#Type):

> To test for [type] equality, compare the Types directly.

Comment: @joeybloggs: Remember to [accept answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you feel answered your questions.